# Error in Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

When trying to create this stored procedure, I'm getting an error:

> *PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement*

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FindDb(
       P_BookId IN BOOKMASTER.BookId%TYPE,
       p_PublisherCode OUT BOOKMASTER.PUBLISHERCODE%TYPE,
       p_ISBNCode OUT BOOKMASTER.ISBNCODE%TYPE,
       p_BookName OUT BOOKMASTER.BOOKNAME%TYPE,
    p_BookType OUT BOOKMASTER.BOOKTYPE%TYPE,
    p_BookLevel OUT BOOKMASTER.BOOKLEVEL%TYPE,
    p_BookCategory OUT BOOKMASTER.BOOKCATEGORY%TYPE,
    p_AuthorNames OUT BOOKMASTER.AUTHORNAMES%TYPE,
    p_PublishedYear OUT BOOKMASTER.PUBLISHEDYEAR%TYPE,
    p_CostPrice OUT BOOKMASTER.COSTPRICE%TYPE,
    p_MRP OUT BOOKMASTER.MRP%TYPE,
    p_BookImage OUT BOOKMASTER.BOOKIMAGE%TYPE)
 AS
BEGIN

  SELECT  PUBLISHERCODE, ISBNCODE, BOOKNAME,BOOKTYPE,BOOKLEVEL,BOOKCATEGORY
 ,AUTHORNAMES,PUBLISHEDYEAR,COSTPRICE,MRP,BOOKIMAGE
  FROM  BOOKMASTER WHERE BOOKID = p_BookId;

END FindDb;
/
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What's your question?  You haven't got an INTO clause - you need one!

Comment: What do you want to achieve in this procedure?

Comment: @Ankur:Its better to create a record and passed that record as `out parameter`

Comment: This is a trivial syntax error which you could have solved for yourself by reading the manual.  The Oracle documentation is comprehensive, online and free: please learn how to use it: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#i7112

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle stored procedure we have to SELECT values into either variables or out parameters.  Please [read the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345).

Try to create your stored procedure in the following manner.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE finddb (
    p_bookid            IN   bookmaster.bookid%TYPE,
    p_publishercode     OUT bookmaster.publishercode%TYPE,
    p_isbncode              OUT bookmaster.isbncode%TYPE,
    p_bookname              OUT bookmaster.bookname%TYPE,
    p_booktype              OUT bookmaster.booktype%TYPE,
    p_booklevel             OUT bookmaster.booklevel%TYPE,
    p_bookcategory      OUT bookmaster.bookcategory%TYPE,
    p_authornames           OUT bookmaster.authornames%TYPE,
    p_publishedyear     OUT bookmaster.publishedyear%TYPE,
    p_costprice             OUT bookmaster.costprice%TYPE,
    p_mrp                   OUT bookmaster.mrp%TYPE,
    p_bookimage             OUT bookmaster.bookimage%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  publishercode,
                isbncode,
                bookname,
                booktype,
                booklevel,
                bookcategory,
                authornames,
                publishedyear,
                costprice,
                mrp,
                bookimage
      INTO  p_publishercode,
                p_isbncode,
                p_bookname,
                p_booktype,
                p_booklevel,
                p_bookcategory,
                p_authornames,
                p_publishedyear,
                p_costprice,
                p_mrp,
                p_bookimage
      FROM  bookmaster
     WHERE  bookid = p_bookid;
END finddb;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're expecting an Oracle stored procedure to work the same way as a SQL Server SP - they are different - in Oracle you need to select INTO variables or a cursor then do something with the values.   If you're just trying to select the values as in SQL server, it doesn't work like that.